# Ember data, how can i use nested(two-depth) json-format for hasMany Relationship

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Generally, Ember HasMany relationship json format is follow,

```
{ "post" : { id:1, title:"this is title", comments:[1,2], writer: ...} }
```

But, i want to use next json format (because, my server return like this)

```
{ "post" : { id:1, title:"this is title",
            comments:[
               {id:1, bodytext:"blarblar...."},
               {id:2, bodytext:"second blarblar...."},
            ], writer: ...} }
```

*How can I use this?

Isn't there any problem in ember store relationship?*

Comment: http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin.html

Comment: Thank you. I've solved this by using embeded:always of DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin.

Answer (score 0):

This is a job for [`EmbeddedRecordsMixin`](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin.html).

If you're implementing the server yourself and it's purpose-built for your ember application, you should consider switching to side-loading instead:

```
{ "post" : { id: 1, 
             title: "this is title",
             comments: [1,2],
             writer: ...
           },
  "comments": [ { id: 1, 
                  bodytext: "blarblar...."
                },
                { id: 2, 
                  bodytext: "second blarblar...."
                }
              ]
}
```

That way, it would be still just one request, but would work for more complicated structures (other than trees) as well.

Comment: I can't change the json format, because server code doesn't like change.
But, I solved that. Thank you.